# Can I safely spray copper fungicide for peach leaf curl during summer?

Tags: diseases, fungus, peaches

My family has a peach tree with severe leaf curl which they did not notice; I picked up some copper octanoate (0.08%) fungicide today as soon as I noticed. With about half the leaves damaged, I'm expecting to lose the peaches this year but I'd like to save the tree for next year.

Is it safe to spray the tree now (late June) in terms of avoiding further damage? I recognize that the copper may be harmful to human health, so any fruit that do form will not be eaten.